# How to disable dynamic directoy creation under koolreport_assets directory in koolreport?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

In our production, we have a load balancer. Because [KoolReport](https://www.koolreport.com) is creating the assets directory dynamically with a random number, so servers directory structure is not in sync and I'm getting following 404 (not found) for koolreport.js file.

[image]

As you can see in the above image that it has some random number in the address. I want to disable dynamic assets subfolder creation in [KoolReport](https://www.koolreport.com) library.

Following is the directory structure created by the [KoolReport](https://www.koolreport.com):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Simply delete the `koolreport_assets` directory, the code will see that it is missing and generate it again even on the server. Just make sure the user/directory has write access.

To change selinix policies on the parent directory where the `koolreport_assets` directory resides, run:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t /public
```